# `dict.pop` ignores the default value set by `collections.defaultdict(default_factory)`

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict, python-collections

Python's [`dict.pop(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) ignores the default value set by [`collections.defaultdict(default_factory)`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) as shown by the following code snippet:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: 1)
d['a']
d['b'] = 2
print(d.pop('a')) # 1
print(d.pop('b')) # 2
print(d.pop('c', 3)) # 3
d.pop('e') # KeyError: 'e'
```

`d` is a `defaultdict(lambda: 1)`. `d.pop('e')` causes a `KeyError`. Is this intended? Shouldn't `d.pop('e')` return `1` since that's the default value set by `defaultdict`?

Comment: Since `defaultdict` doesn't override the `pop()` method, its behavior isn't modified from `dict`.

Comment: You can subclass `defaultdict` and implement this behavior if it's important, but I see no problem to add default return value.

Comment: Although the syntax might be a bit weird you could use: `d.pop('e', d['e'])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**: In summary, defaultDict will make `dict['inexistent-key']` return your default value, anythying else should have the same behaviour as a normal dict.

#### Explanation

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) you linked states that:

> It overrides **one method** [`__missing__()`] and adds **one writable instance variable** [`default_factory`]. The remaining functionality is the same as for the dict class and is not documented here.

That is further specified under the `__missing__()` method itself, which is called by `__getitem__()` on a dict:

> Note that `__missing__()` is not called for any operations besides `__getitem__()`. This means that `get()` will, like normal dictionaries, return `None` as a default rather than using default_factory.

So not only `pop()` will have the same behaviour, `get()` will too. The only way to have the default value would be to straight up use `[key]` on your dict. And if we think about it, it's definitely the most relevant call on a dict.